# Is it possible to create a variable text string in HTML?

Tags: html, xml

I have a document where there's a component name that's repeated hundreds of times. I'm trying to make this document into a template where the component name will change from report to report. Instead of having hundreds of iterations of "Example123" in plain text, I'd like to define a variable text string, for example "&ComponentName;" and use that throughout the template so that any change to that variable changes each instance of the component name. Thereby, creating a situation where anyone can create a new document for different components with one change instead of hundreds. Is something like that possible when just using HTML?

I've tried looking up every element in HTML in w3 schools to see if there's something like this, but to no avail. I've also tried searching stack overflow for this, but I think I might be using the wrong terminology and I'm not sure how else to describe what I'm looking for. When I think of "variable" I'm thinking of "X" which can be defined by the user, but when I look up "variable text in html" I tend to get results about `<var>` which doesn't help in this use case.

I tried to use

```
<script>
const string = "The revolution will not be televised.";
console.log(string);
</script>
```

to see if the text string will appear in output, but nothing appeared and I'm unfamiliar with Javascript.

Comment: Why are your `<script>` tags written like `\<script\>`? If that's in your actual code, those slashes are your issue.

Comment: Yeah, your code minus the slashes works. It will output that string to the console log. But your actual problem is unclear.

Comment: Sorry guys, just unfamiliar with formatting code in stack overflow. Fixed the issue, there's no extra "\"s in the code I'm using.

Comment: Sounds like you need to flag all the instances where the variable should be (probably with a class, then use JS to iterate over `document.querySelectorAll("classNameYouUsed") and set the innerText.

Comment: @Slbox Could be caused by this bug: [Punctuation characters being escaped in code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416802/4642212).

Comment: @mykaf The selector should start with `.` if it’s meant to be a class selector.

Answer (score 0):

Use some plachoder text inside your html, and then replace all the instances of that text with your component name, in javascript:

```js
const placeholder = '@CMPNT@'

const componentName = 'MY COMPONENT NAME'

document.querySelector('.container').innerHTML = document.querySelector('.container').innerHTML.replaceAll(placeholder, componentName)
```

```html
<div class="container">
<p>Lorem @CMPNT@ dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
elit. Vivamus ac scelerisque augue. Donec eu mattis libero. 
Quisque gravida sit amet tellus id @CMPNT@. Orci varius 
natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, 
nascetur ridiculus mus. Suspendisse @CMPNT@ et magna vel 
congue. In non  maximus diam. Suspendisse tristique est 
vitae nibh sollicitudin varius. Integer at dolor vitae felis 
placerat fringilla eu sit amet ipsum. @CMPNT@ euismod ipsum 
eget neque rhoncus sodales. Cras velit dui, tempus at pulvinar 
eget, varius sed @CMPNT@. Donec egestas, erat nec luctus 
suscipit, libero quam maximus mauris, id sagittis ligula 
quam condimentum lacus.</p>
</div>
```